# Lutris terminates with code 256 on operation vc_redist.x86.exe /q

Tags: software-installation, wine

I want to install Escape From Tarkov via Lutris. Judging by the reviews, this is the only working option.

Installing dependencies when starting the Escape From Tarkov installation (config from Lutris source) terminates with code 256. Specifically, the failure occurs at `vc_redist.x86.exe /q`. What could be the problem?

[image: Screenshot]